# Input value turn into infinite loop (RPG battle)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a turn-based battle (RPG style) until my hp or opponent's hp is down to 0, with input a number each turn via a form.

The problem is I have got an infinite loop as soon as the index.js file is loaded. I can't input anything into the form. I tried to exit the function to get the value from the loop. I can now input a number, but it doesn't work in the loop. I tried to scope all the code in a function(), and use callback.

Here is the code:

```js
while((opponant.health > 0) && (player.health > 0)) {
    $('#battlebutton').click(function() {
        attDef = $('#battleinput').val();
        console.log(attDef);
        opponantAttDef = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
        if (attDef == 1 && opponantAttDef == 1) {
            opponant.health = opponant.health - player.strength;
            player.health = player.health - opponant.strength;
            $('#battlelog h3 ol').append('<ul>You attack ' + opponant.name + '.' + opponant.health + ' HP remaining. <br>' + opponant.name + 'attack you. You got ' + player.health + ' remaining </ul>');
        } else if (attDef == 2 && opponantAttDef == 1) {
            player.health = player.health - (opponant.strength / 2);
            $('#battlelog h3 ol').append('<ul>You defend yourself. <br> ' + opponant.name + 'attack you. You got ' + player.health + ' remaining </ul>');
        } else if (attDef == 1 && opponantAttDef == 2) {
            opponant.health = opponant.health - (player.strength / 2);
            $('#battlelog h3 ol').append('<ul>You attack '+ opponant.name +', but it defends itself. Your damage are halved. Your foe still have ' + opponant.health +' HP.</ul>');
        } else if (attDef == 2 && opponantAttDef == 2){
            $('#battlelog h3 ol').append('<ul> You both stand sill. Nothing happens...</ul>');
    } else {
            $('#battlelog h3 ol').append('<ul> Wrong input </ul>');
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="battleinput" value="" placeholder="Att or def ?">
<button id="battlebutton">Yataaaaa !!!</button>
<div id="battlelog">
    <h3>Your battle log :</h3>
    <ol>
             <!-- Battle log -->
    </ol>
```

I want the player to input 1 or 2 each turn, and have the round resolve (opponent att or def is random generated). I want it in an input, not using prompt().

Comment: `while((opponant.health > 0) && (player.health > 0))` is `true` at loading, so your script is adding infinitely an event listener on `#battlebutton`.

Comment: In fact, your `while` loop is not the right thing to use. You should check your actor's HP after clicking your button, then do a different process in function of that.

Comment: I tried, but I don't succeed. I tried a function battle with parameters. I must miss something...

Comment: Nothing changes the values of your while condition inside the loop, so Javascript will never do anything except what is inside the loop (an what does not make sense at all).

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment:

> `while((opponant.health > 0) && (player.health > 0))` is `true` at loading, so your script is adding infinitely an event listener on `#battlebutton`.
>
> In fact, your `while` loop is not the right thing to use. You should check your actors' HP after clicking your button, then do a different process in function of that.

Very simple, replace your `while` statement by a `if` condition that will be checked when you will click on the button.

In that condition, stop the rest of the script and remove the event listener.

Check out what I did below. I allowed myself to add a battle log when the player or the opponent dies (And I corrected many details, like replacing `<ul>` by `<li>`).

```js
// This block is just for make your snippet works correctly.
const Actor = function (name, hp, str) {
  this.name = name;
  this.health = hp;
  this.strength = str;
};

const opponent = new Actor('Opponent', 10, 2),
  player = new Actor('Player', 10, 2);
// The block above is just for make your snippet works correctly.

$('#battlebutton').click(function() {
  // When the player is dead:
  if (player.health <= 0) {
    $('#battlelog ol').append(`
      <li>You died.</li>
    `);
  }

  // When the opponent is dead:
  if (opponent.health <= 0) {
    $('#battlelog ol').append(`
      <li>${opponent.name} died.</li>
    `);
  }
  
  // If one of the actors is dead, turns off the event listener
  // on "Yataaaaa !!!" and doesn't execute what's left.
  if (player.health <= 0
    || opponent.health <= 0) {
    $(this).off('click');
    return;  
  }

  const attDef = +$('#battleinput').val(),
    opponentAttDef = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
      
  if (attDef === 1
    && opponentAttDef === 1) {
    opponent.health = opponent.health - player.strength;
    player.health = player.health - opponent.strength;
    
    $('#battlelog ol').append(`
      <li>You attack ${opponent.name}. ${opponent.health} HP remaining.</li>
    `);
  } else if (attDef === 2
    && opponentAttDef === 1) {
    player.health = player.health - (opponent.strength / 2);
    
    $('#battlelog ol').append(`
      <li> You defend yourself. ${opponent.name} attack you. You got ${player.health} remaining. </li>
    `);
  } else if (attDef === 1
    && opponentAttDef === 2) {
    opponent.health = opponent.health - (player.strength / 2);
    
    $('#battlelog ol').append(`
      <li> You attack ${opponent.name}, but he defends himself. Your damage are halved. Your foe still have ${opponent.health} HP. </li>
    `);
  } else if (attDef === 2
    && opponentAttDef === 2){
    $('#battlelog ol').append(`
      <li> You both stand sill. Nothing happens... </li>
    `);
  } else {
    $('#battlelog ol').append(`
      <li> Wrong input. </li>
    `);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="battleinput" value="" placeholder="Att or def ?">

<button id="battlebutton">Yataaaaa !!!</button>

<div id="battlelog">
  <h3>Your battle log :</h3>
  
  <ol></ol>
</div>
```